# $http headers is not a function - angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, http

I am posting data to `Dynamics CRM` via `SOAP` on my PHP server with `cURL`. After this is done it is giving the entity `GUID` in the form of a HTTP Response header. When attempting to access this via my angular factory and `$http`.

My header is exposed and is able to be viewed in Chrome Developer tools and gives me the `GUID` I need.

The code for accessing the promise data is as follows:

```
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function (data, headers) {

            var array = [];
            array.data = data;
            array.headers = headers('EntityId');
            console.log(array.headers);

            deferred.resolve(array);
        })

return deferred.promise;

//etc
```

The error I get is:

> headers is not a function()

I can however, access some header result such as a status 200 code by using:

```
array.headers = headers;
```

But I need to access my custom header. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: What about [apache_response_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-response-headers.php) ?

Comment: It should be `success(function (data, status, headers)`.

Comment: @Optimistic, did you have to change headers('EntityId') to headers['EntityId'] to make it work?

Comment: Nope. It still resides as headers('EntityID'). I just had to add status to my $http.post as well as headers.

Comment: Great. I also found it weird to see that headers is a method. Learnt something new today. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andy said already, headers is the 3rd parameter of the success callback. So you will have to do this:-

```
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  })
```

I wasn't going to add this as an answer but doing this as I wanted to add that headers is indeed a function.

In my project, I did the below and saw function logged out as type in console. The function returns the value of the header item corresponding to the name passed, if no parameters are passed, returns an object containing all headers.

```
login(user) {
    return this.$http.post(this.url, user)
        .success((data, status, headers, config) => {
            console.log(typeof headers, 'headers'); => prints function
            console.log(headers(), 'headers'); => if you don't pass anything, returns an object containing all headers.

            return response;
        });
}
```

Excerpt from the angular code.

```
function headersGetter(headers) {
var headersObj;

return function(name) {
if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);

if (name) {
  var value = headersObj[lowercase(name)];
  if (value === void 0) {
    value = null;
  }
  return value;
}

return headersObj;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

As per Deprecation Notice on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

the preferred way would be:

```
$http.get('/someUrl')
.then(function(response){
    var array = [];
    array.data = response.data;
    array.headers = response.headers('EntityId');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You parameters for success are incorrect. `headers` is the third parameter.

```
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Check "Usage" section in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http for reference.

Comment: I also thought headers is not a function, but surprisingly, it is. See my answer below for details.

Comment: @AbhishekJain so the correct code would be `headers('EntityId')`?

Comment: Yes, provided EntityId is there in the header. I have tried this by getting Content-type and it works.

Comment: Thanks! Will update answer. `status` must not be a function then.

Comment: Yes, OP's code was not working as status was the second parameter and it is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — a configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and returns a promise.

[The response object has these properties:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.

- **status** – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
- **headers** –{function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
- **config** – {Object}  – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
- **statusText** – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

---

**Angular version == 1.3.5** , Suppose header value has been set "X-AUTH-TOKEN = '*eyJwYXNzd29yZCI6ImFkbWlu*'" in Application Security class after authentication.

```
$scope.postData = "{\"username\" : username , \"password\": password ,\"email\" :email}";

$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/API/authenticate',
            data: postData,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "X-Login-Ajax-call": 'true'
            }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.data == 'ok') {
                $cookies['X-AUTH-TOKEN']=response.headers('X-AUTH-TOKEN');
                // below put,put,putObject Cookies value is valid for Angular version >= 1.4
                // $cookies.putObject('X-AUTH-TOKEN',response.headers('X-AUTH-TOKEN'); 
                window.location.replace('/');
            }
            else {

                // Error Message...
            }
        });
```